# Restricting access to data by user in Spring with Spring Expression Language

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a task management application, where my tasks are defined like so:

```
@Entity
@Data
public class TaskRecord {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @Column(length = 999)
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<User> users;
}
```

I want to wire things up such that a user can only retrieves tasks that s/he is in the Set of users for.

A `User` object has a unique `id` and I've configured my `Principal` object to have the correct `User` as a member (following successful authentication).

Is using `@PostAuthorize` with Spring Expression Language a good way to go about doing this? This is what I have and it works but I am skeptical about its quality or worthwhileness.

```
@Repository
public interface TaskRepository extends CrudRepository<TaskRecord, Long> {
    @Override
    @PostAuthorize("!returnObject.users.?[id == principal.user.id].empty")
    TaskRecord findOne(Long id);
}
```

Also is the use of empty at the end the right way to go about this? It feels a bit hackish.

Finally, is there a way to do this with `@PreAuthorize` so I do not expose the `findOne` result to the JVM?